# Flash .ROM on OEM PC

Tags: bios, updates, flash

I have a custom .ROM with updated microcode that i want to flash but there is no option in bios to flash any BIOS. My PC is OEM HP with modded Xeon e5450 so I updated the ROM that I extracted from original InstallShield bios updater from HP site. Now I'm stuck cause I cannot use my .rom.

I hope the updated rom will solve maximum fan speeds I have right now... And increase performance. 3ghz but showing 2.6 clock speed in CPU-Z...

Is there any way I can accomplish the update or it is not worth the work and the fan speeds wil remain going on maximum speed? Will I lose any performance for casual work usage? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To flash the rom you need the CH341A eeprom read/writer with the 8 pole chip clamp as on here https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/DIP8-IC-test-Clip-SOIC8-SOP8-IC-Test-Clip-IC-flash-clip-For-BIOS-93-25/534941_32395906570.html

I have used devices like this to read/write all kind of eeproms.